# How can a submit button made to be act as a link too?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm doing a Quiz project: The idea is to implement almost 25 questions in which each question occupies each HTML page with 4 radio buttons and a submit button and a reset button as well.On clicking the submit button it should take the user to the next page as well as submit the data to the server. How to achieve this dual behaviour?

I tried this:

```
<form action="cba.php" method="post">
    <a href="abc.html">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </a>
</form>
```

But this does only one purpose: Acting as a link without submitting the data.

Comment: On submit of a form, do `header("Location: location-here")`.

Comment: Can u be more specific i,e where to add this code?

Comment: On your CBA.php form add that.

Comment: remove the <A - it is not valid HTML. Why would you want a link around the submit? Just style the button as a link. If  you want to submit the form to cba and ignore the result, and then change the page to abc thereafter, you need to use AJAX or a redirect header as RepeaterCreeper said

Comment: Please be specific

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: Why is there a form and input at all? Just make the anchor look like a button...

Comment: out of imagination what you want to do?

Comment: @AhmedGinani I can only think he wants to submit to cba AND change the page to abc

Comment: I'm doing a Quiz project:
          The idea is to implement almost 25 questions in which each question occupies each HTML page with 4 radio buttons and a submit button and a reset button as well.On clicking the submit button it should take the user to the next page as well as submit the data to the server.How to achieve this dual behaviour?

Comment: @mplungjan Absolutely

Comment: @jamesgeorge007 If that's the case, you could work with `$.ajax` or Javascript and then later on just submit all of the data at the same time. However, for mostly PHP and no JS, then it would be quite a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to redirect the user after submitting the form, you can use :

```
header("Location: yourlink");
```

in the php script you called `cba.php`.

Otherwise, i'm not sure it is possible to redirect the user before sending him the php script page.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it would be a smoother experiance to handle this via ajax, but it can be acheived in just php by creating a redirect in the form processing code (as mentioned in comments and a current answer).

I believe your issue is with the fact that the same proccessing code (cba.php) will be called every step of the way, so you need a way for each quiz section to define the next section.

This can be done with a hidden field instead of the link code you tried:

```
<form action="cba.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="next-page" value="abc.html">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Then i cba.php, you redirect to the value contained in this hidden field:

```
//save the data from the form, then
header("Location: " . $_POST['next-page']);
```

Comment: What is the use of <INPUT Type="hidden">?

Comment: It holds the value of the next page of the quiz, so `cba.php` knows where to redirect to after the data is saved

Comment: I just have 1 PHP code and almost 25 HTML pages.Where should I place this code in my PHP file?
I meant as the first line or anywhere etc

Comment: After the code that saves the data, cant really be more specific as i dont know how your php works.